# Update Manager window appears. How to stop it?

Tags: 22.04

Update Manager Window automatically appears every 10 min. It says there are no updates available. How to stop it? I have already tried setting 'never' of checking for updates. That has not solved the problem.

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.2.
[image: Image of the window]

It is software updater popup window.

Comment: are you sure its from the software updater and not from Extension  Manager?

Comment: There is 'A' icon in the window.

Comment: It works normally again.

Comment: This popup appears again from time to time. I don't wanna touch update-notifier package, so I have leaved it as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open a therminal type the code below and press enter:

   ```
   sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
   ```
2. Open the "startup applications preferences" and uncheck the "update notifier", like the image below:

[image: startup apps preferences]

3. Close the dialogue window and reboot your computer.

Comment: It is the solution. No spontaneous popups anymore.

Comment: One is glad to be of service :)